# How get the difference between 2 BMP files using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, compare, bmp

I'm trying to compare between 2 bmp files looks the same but with Mercury.FileCompare the result return false.

i want to get the difference in precentege? any suggest?
Maybe some way to take bitmap and draw the image as array of number between 0-255?

Thanks

Comment: do you want to compare then in QTP or you want to use pure vbscript?

Comment: Actually the final target is to use it in QTP but i didn't find a way that is not checkpoint.

Comment: what if you convert both to a base64 string, then compare?

Answer (score 0):

You can still use the old way to compare bitmaps

```
Set objMercuryFilecompare = CreateObject("Mercury.FileCompare")
If objMercuryFilecompare.IsEqualBin("C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test1.bmp" , "C:\Users\pankaj.jaju\Desktop\test2.bmp",0,1) Then
msgbox "match"
else
msgbox "mismatch"
end if
Set objMercuryFilecompare = nothing
```

Comment: As you can see up, I wrote that i'm familiar with this function. I want something that returns the difference! So I can decide, for example, if the diff is less than 10% the test pass. Not 100% similarity

Comment: Thats bit tricky. Take a look at [this](http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2011/comparing-images-and-creating-image-diffs/) for some ideas.

Comment: Thanks. but i need something in VBscript. Any other idea?